# Is "a rant on <topic>" equivalent to "a rant about <topic>"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

Is it correct to rant on something? Or is ranting about the only correct usage of the word? E.g. "He's been ranting on his landlord all evening".

Comment: "About" certainly isn't the only preposition that can follow noun or verb "rant" ("concerning" would be fine, maybe even "re" or "anent"),  but your example sounds a bit odd. Sounding odd doesn't mean it's incorrect, just that it's suboptimal.

Comment: I would never use rant on something. It's not idiomatic. However, what is idiotmagnet {eggcorn joke) is: to rant on and on **about something**.

Comment: Very similar to *”talking”*. You can talk about something and talk on some subject but you wouldn’t talk on the teacher- only about.

Answer (score 0):

"Rant about" is more common than "rant on". [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rant%20on%2Crant%20about&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true)

[image]

This is the google book search result for ["rant on"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rant%20on%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

Used as a *verb*, I would always use it with '*about*'; used as a noun I would use both.

Comment: You should look at how many examples use "Rant" as a surname.

Comment: I have looked at the results, that's why I have posted the book search link. I have looked uptil page 3, I would say "Rant surname" and "rant verb and noun" are in equal measure.